# Gradle Sync Failure In Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

As soon as I open an Android Studio project, I get a warning saying "Gradle Sync Failed" and this error:

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext cannot be cast to org.gradle.internal.logging.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext
```

My build.gradle is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I've tried the suggested fixes and a clean install several times to no avail. I have OSX 10.10 with JDK 8 installed.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post your build.gradle files in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **slf4j*** jars files from `/Library/Java/Extensions`.

Use below command to see files in `Extensions` directory:

`ls /Library/Java/Extensions/`

See [this](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Installing-Gradle-on-Mac-Ox-X-td4283558.html) question and it's answer [here](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Installing-Gradle-on-Mac-Ox-X-tp4283558p4433560.html)

I hope it's helps you.

Comment: Hey, I think thats the problem! How do I delete files from that folder? I can only access it from the Terminal and typing rm file.java isn't working. For example, typing "rm -Rf /Library/Java/Extensions/logback-classic.jar" gets me a permission denied.

Comment: try `sudo rm -R [file name]`.

Comment: sudo rm -R slf4j-api.jar Got Me:
rm: slf4j-api.jar: No such file or directory

Comment: Try to check with `ls` command to see the file list or check if any subdirectory like `.java` in `Extensions`. I can't able to test it because i am not using OSX. :(

Comment: Can you able to delete files? Can you able to sync your project?

Comment: I had to delete the entire /Library/Java/Extensions/ folder and remake it. Now I can sync, though.